# Dynamically extracting multiple parts of a string Perl/Regex

Tags: regex, perl

So this probably has a very simple solution but I'm pretty green in Perl....  For simplicity sake, I'll use a simple example:

```
# extract hours, minutes, seconds
$time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/;  # match hh:mm:ss format
$hours = $1;
$minutes = $2;
$seconds = $3;
```

The application I'm writing allows the user to input a regex string that may have multiple matches like in the example.  I'm looking for a way to know how many `$<n>`'s are available to me based on the regex the user entered.  Is there a way to see if $1,$2....$n were defined during the current matching process?  I'm using:
`$parsed_response =~ /$block_start_regex/;`
where $block_start_regex could be something like `$block_start_regex=qr/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;` or whatever the user enters.....

Also, if I match earlier in the code on 9 variables, are they all set back to undefined the next time I run a regex match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're matching a regex, you can capture 'matches' into an array:

```
my @matches = $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/g;
```

This will then match multiple times, and plonk 'hits' in to the `@matches` array.

So to take your above example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "11:22:33 somefhunakdawer 14:32:17"; 

my @matches = $str =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/g;

print Dumper \@matches;
```

This will give you an array with:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11',
          '22',
          '33',
          '14',
          '32',
          '17'
        ];
```

Although - you'll have to read you array in 3-element chunks.

Alternatively - you can 'group' your capture, depending precisely what you're after:

```
my $str = "11:22:33 somefhunakdawer 14:32:17"; 
my $pattern = qr/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/; 

my @matches = $str =~ m/($pattern)/g;

print Dumper \@matches;
```

This'll give you:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11:22:33',
          '11',
          '22',
          '33',
          '14:32:17',
          '14',
          '32',
          '17'
        ];
```

It's a bit hard to take an input pattern and 'merge' it, but you could do something like:

```
my $str = "11:22:33 somefhunakdawer 14:32:17"; 
my $pattern = qr/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/; 

my @matches = map {[ split /:/ ]} $str =~ m/($pattern)/g;

print Dumper \@matches;
```

This selects instances of `$pattern`, but then uses `map` to split it on a delimiter, into a sub array. Thus we get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '11',
            '22',
            '33'
          ],
          [
            '14',
            '32',
            '17'
          ]
        ];
```

In both cases though, you need a bit more logic to it - you can tell, if you've got 3 capture groups in your input, you'll have a multiple of 3 in your `@matches`.

If you wanted to dynamically detect, you could probably double-match:

```
my $str = "11:22:33 somefhunakdawer 14:32:17"; 
my $pattern = qr/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/; 

my @matches = $str =~ m/$pattern/;
my $num_groups = @matches; 
@matches = $str =~ m/$pattern/g; 

while ( @matches ) { 
   print "Group : ", join ("-", splice ( @matches, 0, $num_groups )),"\n";
}
```

The first capture (without `g`) tells you how many capture groups this pattern generates.

Then you run a second capture - with `g` - to repeat the capture into the array, and then extract a number of capture groups from the list of matches.

Although note - this approach will fail if there's variable-capture groups in the input pattern - e.g.

```
my $pattern = qr/(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?::(\d{2}))?/;
```

which has optional 'seconds' match

Comment: Yep, simply storing them in the array gave me enough to use my basic perl knowledge to get it working.  The other grouping and capturing methods are very educational, thank you!